# Prefix. Suffix. Infix. Outfix?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My prefix for gains
>
> My suffix is bled
>
> My infix in veins
>
> My outfix is bed

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess:

> **beancod** (or mostly bean-cod)

*My prefix for gains*

> **bean**cod; a variety of *bean*s are good for muscle gain

*My suffix is bled*

> bean**cod**; cod is a type of fish and fishes are generally bled before cooking

*My infix in veins*

> bean**co**d; veins carry deoxygenated blood which also contains **$CO_2$** back to the heart

*My outfix is bed*

> **be**anco**d**; *bed* is its outfix since it is split in two parts *'be'* and *'d'* around *'anco'*

Comment: An obscure word, but you got it! :)

Comment: I'm quite surprised this is the answer, the third line especially seems very loose. Was this the intention @Avi ?

Comment: @hexomino Yes - it was a precarious balance between a fairly obscure word, a rhyme, and an outfix

Comment: TBH, I'm quite surprised myself @hexomino, it was a wild guess after an hour of searching.